# Accessing Access 2010 (x64) .accdb database from WPF application (targetting x86)?

Tags: wpf, x86, oledb, ms-access-2010, ms-access

I have the following environment:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
MS office (with Access) 2010 64-bit

I am developing an application in VS 2010 and the application is being developed for x86 CPU.
I am using DataSet to connect to the database and I am using the NewConnection wizard to connect to the database.

I want to use an access database for data storage.  (.accdb file)

I downloaded and installed the Access Database engine (64 bit).

When i use:

```
Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 - I get an error that the database format is not readable!!
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 - I get an error that the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 driver is not registered on the local machine!
```

Please help me find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no answer, this is the solution applied:
I installed the Access Database Engine, available as a download from Microsoft and it worked.

This was the latest version available and had the appropriate driver for database access.